# What happened to the future Flash who stopped Barry from saving his mother in season 1?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

When Barry went back to save his mother in season 1, he was hiding in a room and when he was about to go out, there was a Flash who signaled at him to not do it, to not save her. But when he went back in time to save his mother at the end of season 2, that specific Flash was not there anymore. I'm assuming he must have come from a further future, and he has experienced Flashpoint and the events post-Flashpoint to know that saving Nora Allen and getting her killed again would later cause Caitlin to become Killer Frost and Cisco to lose his brother and some other mess.

Which is why - I think - he raced back to the night Nora died to tell Barry from before Flashpoint to not save his mother. I'm wondering if anyone knows what happened to that Future Flash, just in case I miss anything from season 3. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The flash from 2024 signals the S01 Barry to not save his mother, because the time for Flashpoint has not yet come to pass. In order for the timeline to stay intact, 2024 Barry signals S01 to not save his mother, since doing that would bring Flashpoint (and its damages) early on in the timeline.

In season 2, he is very much there. He is the one who saves 11-year old Barry, and does not stick around for Nora Allen's death at the hands of Thawne that would happen (probably due to either the grief of his mother dying or him seeing that way too many times). Barry saves his mother after his younger self has been whisked away by his future self from 2024, and that is why we do not see him in the S02 finale.

Ultimately, we do not know the whereabouts or the future of the future flash from 2024; he must have sped back to the future, since Thawne describes the necessity to create the Flash in order for him to return to his time because the Flash (from 2024) was gone.

*What we do know* is that the present Barry's future is the 2024 Flash, evidenced from the newspaper article that Iris West-Allen will eventually write.

And make no mistake, this is not the 2024 version that we saw in the 3rd season's episode 19, since that Flash was from a future where Savitar would kill Iris; while the future has changed due to Savitar getting erased; which means that the timeline is restored - not completely, but enough for it to follow the future of the original timeline in which the Crisis article is written by Iris West-Allen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that future Barry was erased from the timeline because he had both parents and now that thawne killed his mother he got erased

Comment: Welcome to this site. This should probably be posted as a comment to the question. Once you have [sufficient reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

So far, there is no definitive answer as to what happened to that future Flash. There are theories, but no official answers have been given.

Comment: While technically correct, I sort of doubt the OP will decide to marked this as the accepted answer :-)